# Easy way to add a closing quote in an ellipsized over-flowed text

Tags: php, css, styles, quote, ellipsis

I have a div with a text inside. If the text overflows it's div, It is shortened with an ellipsis at the end. What I want to do is to add a double-quote after it's ellipse so that it will look like this:

"The quick bro..."

Here's my code:

```
<html><body>
  <div style="width: 100px;background: #CCCCCC;">
    <div style="overflow:hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;">"The quick brown fox"
  </div></div>
</body></html>
```

Is there an easy way/technique to do this or do you need to create your own custom ellipsis instead?

Thanks all!

Comment: This is the only way I found [Change the three dots (ellipses) (…) to custom characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455564/change-the-three-dots-ellipses-to-custom-characters-in-vb-net-datagridvi) or [Replace Excerpt Ellipsis with Permalink](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/replace-excerpt-ellipsis-with-permalink/)

Comment: I found a related question and seems like there's no CSS solution to it: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793473/text-overflow-ellipsis-on-left-side)

Answer (score 5):

CSS [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) can be configured with custom characters, for example:

```
.customEllipsis {
    overflow:hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: '…"';
}
```

However, support is **experimental** and the above example will currently *only* work in Firefox.

For cross-browser support you will have to modify the output in PHP (since the question is tagged with PHP) on the server or with JavaScript on the client.

**Update 2015-07-29** `text-overflow` is now [fully supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow#Browser_compatibility) by all modern browsers.

**Update 2016-07-01** It is possible that moving to the Blink web engine broke this as I would have tested it on Chrome - see [this Blink defect](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=250817). Also it doesn't look like it works in Edge.

So there is currently **no** cross-browser solution using [`text-overflow: <string>`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#overflow-string). It gets worse because the `<string>` functionality is marked "at risk" so it could be dropped if "interoperable implementations are not found".

Comment: Thanks @PhilipMurphy it seems that `<string>` is no longer working in the year since my last update

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I solved a similar problem, using :before and :after pseudo-selectors to make it work:

```css
.truncate {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 150px;
  padding-right: 7px; /* adjust based on font size */
}
.truncate:before {
  content: "\"";
}
.truncate:after {
  content: "\"";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="truncate">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this doesn't satisfy the final result required by the OP.